# pipe commands inside find -exec?

Tags: shell, find, pipe

Let's suppose I want to find all `.txt` files and search for some string. I would do:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec egrep -iH 'something' '{}' \;
```

What if I want to do a more complex filtering, like this:

```
egrep something file.txt | egrep somethingelse | egrep other
```

Inside find -exec? (or similar)

Please keep in mind that I'm searching for a solution that I could easily type when I need it. I know that this could be done with a few lines using a shell script, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you must do it from within find, you need to call a shell:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'grep -EiH something "$1" | grep -E somethingelse | grep -E other' sh {} \;
```

Other alternatives include using `xargs` instead:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" | 
    xargs -I{} grep -EiH something {} | 
        grep -EiH somethingelse | 
            grep -EiH other
```

Or, much safer for arbitrary filenames (assuming your `find` supports `-print0`):

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | 
    xargs -0 grep -EiH something {} | 
        grep -Ei somethingelse | 
            grep -Ei other
```

Or, you could just use a shell loop instead:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -d '' file; do 
        grep -Ei something "$file" | 
            grep -Ei somethingelse | 
                grep -Ei other
    done
```

Comment: The first one is exactly what I was looking for. Extremely simple and small enough to type depending on my needs. Thanks.

Comment: ... and `xargs` could also be used as `xargs -I {} sh -c '...' sh {}`, if one wanted to (it makes it possible to run parallel jobs with `-P` if one wanted to).

Comment: I find the first one working for me but I'm confused why there's an extra `sh` in the very end as in `... sh {} \;`. Would you mind clarifying? @terdon

Comment: @BosonBear because that will become $0 in the sh script, you can use any arbitrary string. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389706/22222

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This answer is **not preferred**, but is left here for comparison and illustration of potentially dangerous pitfalls in bash scripting.

---

You can put `bash` (or another shell) as your `-exec` command:

```bsh
find -type -f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'egrep -iH something "{}" | egrep somethingelse | egrep other' \;
```

One of the downsides of doing it this way is that it creates more potential for nested quoting issues as your commands get more complex. If you want to avoid that, you can break it out into a `for`-loop:

```bsh
for i in $(find -type -f -name "*.txt"); do
  if egrep -iH something "$i" | egrep somethingelse | egrep other; then 
    echo "Found something: $i"
  fi
done
```

Comment: The first one is exactly what I was looking for. Extremely simple and small enough to type depending on my needs. Thanks.

Comment: That `for` loop is a very bad idea.Also known as [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: This `"{}"` in your first command may even lead to code injection. Imagine you got files from me and there's a file literally named `" & rm -rf ~ & : ".txt`. Luckily for you `-type -f` is invalid, it just saved your home directory. Fix the typo and try again. :) terdon did it right: `find … -exec sh -c '… "$1" …' foo {} \;`.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Yeah, the `-type -f` is a typo I make constantly when using `find`, and I didn't notice it in my answer. Whoops. terdon's answer is better, but I'll leave this for comparative purposes.

Comment: @terdon: tx for referencing  the mywiki.wooledge.org page. It's nice to have a bunch of GPs neatly summarized in one place.

Comment: To improve site readability & ease of use, e.g. by new users, do consider at least adding a note at the top of yr post (by editing it) to signal the fact that yr `for ... done` loop-based answer is **not preferred** and left for reason "XYZ".... If not unwitting visitors might credit that particular post with upvotes (as seen already).  I've seen many SE visitors not read the fine prints (i.e. the comments following an answer).  They just stop at the nbr of upvotes. Upvotes are often seen as a seal of approval by some, who tend to accept whatever has apparently been positively sanctioned.