# Count lines in csv files nested in subdir using find exec

Tags: ubuntu, find, pipe, exec

I'd like to run two piped commands on the results of `find` on some nested csv files, but I miserably fail.

Here is the idea:

```bsh
$ find ./tmp/*/ -name '*.csv' -exec tail -n +2 {} | wc -l \;
```

in order **not** to count the header row of each CSV file.

The command is failing on:

```
wc: ';': No such file or directory
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Do I really need to do a `for` loop in that case?
E.g.:

```bsh
$ for f in ./tmp/*/*.csv; do tail -n +2 ${f} | wc -l; done
```

but with that I'm losing the nice output of `find` which does include the filename along the count.

I'm also losing the file name when using this solution: [pipe commands inside find -exec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507023/pipe-commands-inside-find-exec)

```bsh
$ find ./tmp/*/ -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' f; do tail -n +2 "${f}" | wc -l; done
```

A little precision; when I speak about the filename that gets printed, it's because I'm used to the following result when calling the commands on a single file:

```
$ tail -n +2 | wc -l ./tmp/myfile.csv 
2434 ./tmp/myfile.csv
```

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Are you sure about `tail -n +2 | wc -l ./tmp/myfile.csv`? Its `wc` does not read from the pipe. (`... | wc -l` or `... | wc -l file -` would, but the former won't print the name of the file(s) whose lines come fro the pipe, while the latter won't read `file`'s lines _from_ the pipe).

Comment: Does any of the CSV files have (or _could_ they have) embedded newlines in any fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write

```bsh
find ... -exec foo | bar \;
```

the vertical bar is interpreted by your shell before `find` is invoked. The left hand of the resulting pipeline is `find ... -exec foo`, which obviously gives a "missing argument to `-exec'" error; the right hand of the pipeline is `bar`.

Protecting the vertical bar from the shell, as in

```bsh
find ... -exec foo \| bar \;
```

is of no help, because the first token after `-exec` is interpreted by `find` as a command and all the following tokens, up to (but not including) the `;` or `+` terminator, are taken as arguments to that command.

See [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/315749) for a thorough explanation.

To use a pipeline with `-exec` you need to invoke a shell. For instance:

```bsh
find ./tmp/*/ -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  printf "%s %s\n" "$(tail -n +2 "$1" | wc -l)" "$1"' mysh {} \;
```

Then, to avoid risking an "argument list too long" error, `./tmp/*/` can be rewritten as

```bsh
find ./tmp -path './tmp/*/*' ...
```

or, more precisely, to also exclude `tmp`'s hidden subdirectories (as `./tmp/*/` would likely do by default), as

```bsh
find ./tmp -path './tmp/.*' -prune -o -path './tmp/*/*' ...
```

Finally, you may use the faster `-exec ... {} +` variant, which avoids invoking a shell for any single found file. For instance, with `awk` in place of `tail` and `wc`:

```bsh
find ./tmp -path './tmp/.*' -prune -o -path './tmp/*/*' \
  -name '*.csv' -exec awk '
    BEGIN { skip = 1 }
    FNR > skip { lc[FILENAME] = (FNR - skip) }
    END { for (f in lc) print lc[f],f }' {} +
```

(Note that `awk` also counts those malformed lines that do not end in a newline character, while `wc` does not).

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is to essentially subtract 1 from each `wc -l`, this is very simple and clean:

```
find [whatever you want] -exec wc -l {} + | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1-1/e'
```